# Delete tagLabel in input-Field with tagit

Tags: javascript, jquery, tag-it

I use https://github.com/aehlke/tag-it this Addon for Autocomplete Tagging

The user just can take labels out of the existing array **sampleTags**

Before the tag is added I check whether the element is in Array or not

```
beforeTagAdded: function(evt, ui) {  
               var counter = jQuery.inArray(ui.tagLabel, sampleTags);

               if (counter != -1 ) { return true; }
       else { alert('This word is not in array'); return false; }  
},
```

But the input then is not deleted .

How can I do this?

**jsFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/zqDXL/3/

Comment: Can you explain more which input should be deleted and when? btw, geige is not there :)

Comment: :) ! e.g. if you type in 'Klav' you can choose 'Klavier'. But when you type in 'klaw' and you press enter the alert opens up, but 'klaw' is not deleted!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
if (counter != -1) {
    return true;
} else {
    alert('This word is not in array');
    $('.tagit-new input').val('');
    return false;
}
```

**Demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/FUVuT/)**